# How to list ssh keys?

Tags: ssh

How can I list all keys which are accessible by my ssh?

I want to see if ssh has the right keys.

My ssh can't connect the server, although it has the keys, but I don't know if there are the right key among them.

Comment: While running an `ssh` command specify the `-v` option and observe what key(s) it uses.

Comment: A good hint, thanks. It helped me to see which key was used to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh-add -l
```

This command will list the keys that are loaded in the SSH agent, ie. currently available to SSH.

You can also specify a keyfile explicitly:

```
ssh -i ~/path/to/key/file ...
```

This may be necessary if the host you're connecting to is limiting number of keyfile attempts. If the limit is too low and you have a lot of keys added to the agent, SSH may not be able to try the right key before it reaches the limit. In that case `-i` tells it explicitly which key to use. There's a corresponding configfile option too if you don't want to have to specify it explicitly each time.